# Law of Total (Conditional) Probability and Filtration

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

The law of total probability establishes that

$$
\mathbb{P}[A\mid C] = \sum_{n}\mathbb{P}[A\mid C\cap B_n]\,\mathbb{P}.[B_n\mid C] 
$$

Suppose that I have a filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $A_t$ and $B_t$ are  $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted stochastic processes. In particular $B_t$ can be either $1$ or $0$. Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an interval.
I am wondering if I can apply the law of total probability and write

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}[A_t\in I\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]&=&\mathbb{P}[A_t\in I\mid \mathcal{F}_{t-1}\cap \{B_t=1\}]\,\mathbb{P}[B_n=1\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]+\\
& & +\mathbb{P}[A_t\in I\mid \mathcal{F}_{t-1}\cap \{B_t=0\}]\,\mathbb{P}[B_n=0\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}] 
\end{eqnarray}.
$$ 
Is the writing above formally correct?

Comment: Yes this is a valid argument, the extension to your case is quite straightforward to prove with the definition of conditional expectation with respect to sigma algebra (if you don"t forget that conditioning with respect to an event mean conditioning with respect the (trivial) sigma algebra it generates). Best regard.

Comment: @TheBridge How is the conditioning thing well-defined? One is a collection of subsets while the other is a collection of sample points

Answer (score 0):

No.

1. I think you mean $\mathbb E$ instead of $\mathbb P$
2. It does not make sense to take the intersection of a collection of events (e.g. $\mathcal F_{t-1}$) and a collection of sample points (e.g. $(B_t = 1)$). Perhaps you meant $\sigma((B_t = 1))$.
3. Careful about the extension you're trying to make here. You seem to be thinking we can do something like:

$$E[X] = E[Y] \to E[X|\mathscr F] = E[Y|\mathscr F]$$

And is that really possible? Go back to the definition of conditional expectation.

4. If you want specifically to condition on $(B_t = 1)$, try (note the correction for the indices):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\left\{A_t\in I\right\}}\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]&=&\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\left\{A_t\in I\right\}| \{B_t=1\}}\mid \mathcal{F}_{t-1}]\,\mathbb{P}[B_t=1\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]+\\
& & +\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\left\{A_t\in I\right\}| \{B_t=0\}}\mid \mathcal{F}_{t-1}]\,\mathbb{P}[B_t=0\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}] 
\end{eqnarray}.
$$

where we seem to have $E[1_{A|B}] := P(A|B)$, where in our case $A = \{A_t \in I \}$ and $B = \{B_t=1\}$, **not that the above should be correct or sensible:**

For example, what is $1_{A|B}$?

$1_{A|B}(\omega) = 1 \times 1_{\omega \in A} + 0 \times 1_{\omega \in A^C}$ but $\omega \in B$?

So what if $\omega \notin B$? What is the value of $1_{A|B}$ (This is similar to asking what is the $P(A|B)$ if $P(B) = 0$)? What kind of event or object is $A|B$ anyway?

Well assuming $1_{A|B}(\omega)$ is a well-defined object and a well-defined random variable, we seem to have:

$$E[1_{A|B}(\omega)|\mathscr F_{t-1}] E[1_{B}(\omega)|\mathscr F_{t-1}]$$

$$ = E[ E[1_{A|B}(\omega)|\mathscr F_{t-1}] 1_{B}(\omega)|\mathscr F_{t-1}]$$

Now if $B_t$ is previsible, we have:

$$ = E[1_{A|B}(\omega) 1_{B}(\omega) |\mathscr F_{t-1}]$$

///ly, we have

$$E[1_{A|B^C}(\omega)|\mathscr F_{t-1}] E[1_{B^C}(\omega)|\mathscr F_{t-1}]$$

$$ = E[1_{A|B^C}(\omega) 1_{B^C}(\omega) |\mathscr F_{t-1}]$$

It seems that

$$E[1_{A|B}(\omega) 1_{B}(\omega) |\mathscr F_{t-1}] + E[1_{A|B^C}(\omega) 1_{B^C}(\omega) |\mathscr F_{t-1}] = E[1_A | \mathscr F_{t-1}]$$

---

Possibly related section from Probability w/ Martingales:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\mathbb{P}[A_t\in I]$ (which is as you noticed $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{A_t\in I\}}]$ ), I corrected the post accordingly.

Comment: @DP1981 What about the collection of events intersecting an event? :| That is not well-defined

Comment: Yes you are perfectly right, I am thinking how to fix it.

Comment: @DP1981 pls let me know. This seems very interesting :D

Comment: $A\mid B$ and $1_{A\mid B}$ are not well-defined objects.

Comment: @StefanHansen I know...

Comment: Then why would you assume that it is?

Comment: @StefanHansen Perhaps OP can come up w/ well-defined objects that have the same idea as those

Comment: Or perhaps you're making the OP more confused than he/she was at first.